# Two program on different VMs experience reply timeouts unless pinging

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ping

I've encountered a very odd issue.

I've got 2 VMs, each running an identical program (a pub/sub middleware). The programs have to communicate by sending an event from and to each other.

The program indicates the sender experiences a reply time out, and true enough, the receiver does not receive any event though the sender has sent one. So, I check if the VMs can reach each other through pinging. This is possible. Using the same address as for the pinging, I retry communications between the VMs. And now it suddenly works (i.e., event is sent, received and replied to and reply is received)! But, I turn off my pinging now and it doesn't work anymore.

The VMs both have a NAT and two bridged adapters (one to my host wifi and one to my host ethernet)

This is bizarre, they can only communicate when they are also pinging?

Any advice on this weird issue?

Sometimes the effect persists for some time (in the order of seconds) after the pinging has stopped...

Comment: How are configured the virtual interfaces? host? bridge? nat?

Comment: Should've mentioned that, added